# SBT Autoplugin and task modification with "dependsOn"

Tags: sbt

I've created an Autoplugin for an SBT project to launch middleware inside Docker containers for integration tests (Zookeeper and Kafka).

My first version without Autoplugin was to add manually in the projects settings such as :

```
(test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn zkStart
```

That was working very well.

Now with an Autoplugin, I've the following code

```
  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    (test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn ZookeeperPlugin.zkStart
  )
```

but Zookeeper is no longer start before tests.

when I do

```
[core_akka_cluster] $ inspect test
[info] Task: Unit
[info] Description:
[info]  Executes all tests.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/xx/Projects/../../}core_akka_cluster/test:test
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:394
```

We can see that the setting test:test is provided by the default SBT values.

When I manually add the previous settings in the build definition of my project, this works once more and we have the following analysis

```
[core_akka_cluster] $ inspect test
[info] Task: Unit
[info] Description:
[info]  Executes all tests.
[info] Provided by:
[info]      [info]  {file:/Users/xx/Projects/../../}core_akka_cluster/test:test
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:394
[info]  (com.ingenico.msh.sbt.KafkaPluginSettings) KafkaPlugin.scala:36
```

Any idea about precedence in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making the auto plugin a triggered plugin?
Since `test` is also added by an auto plugin (`JvmPlugin`) by sbt, you should require `JvmPlugin`.